# How to Stream data and add to list outside of Build Function using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Map() called `myData` that holds multiple lists. I want to use a Stream to populate one of the lists in the `Map`. For this StreamBuilder will not work as it requires a return and I would like to use `List.add()` functionality.

```
Map<String, List<Widget>> myData = {
  'list1': [],
  'list2': [],
  'list3': [],
  'list4': []
};
```

How can I fetch information from FireStore but add it to the list instead of returning data?

Like this but this wouldn't work.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: // my snapshot from firestore,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      myData['list1'].add(Text(doc['color']));
    });
  },
),
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StreamBuilder does not fit for this task. Even if you manage to do it (actually there is a way :) )- it might be rebuilt by higher level widgets without new data and you will end up with duplicates in list.

All the WidgetBuilders and `build` methods in widgets serve only for displaying UI

You need to subscribe to a stream. If you want to do it using widget, then you need to create a custom widget extending `StatefulWidget`. `StatefulWidget` state has lifecycle methods (`initState` and `dispose`) so it will allow to correctly manage `StreamSubscription`.

Here is example code:

```dart
class StreamReader extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StreamReaderState createState() => _StreamReaderState();
}

class _StreamReaderState extends State<StreamReader> {

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscription = myStream.listen((data) {
      // do whatever you want with stream data event here
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel(); // don't forget to close subscription
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return your widgets here
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I did manage to come up with another way but is very clunky. I think once I get the page behaving as I want I am going to try to implement this! Again thank you so much this was extremely helpful!